# Is there a word or synonym for "turning inside out?"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am trying to find the word for the act of turning oneself inside out, with respect more to showing one's feelings on the outside instead of supressing it.

The closest words I can come up with are explode, expound, expand, express. Extricate? Is there a word that starts with Ex....? I can't remember, it's probably a word I learnt in childhood but for the life of me I cannot remember.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you’re looking for *evert*?

Comment: [Word Hippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/bare_your_soul.html#/) has synonyms, but the closest fits here are multi-word (bare one's soul // speak openly / frankly / freely // get it off one's chest  ....// There's also _being an extrovert_ for the stative sense.

Comment: Self-revelation, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

**Expose** seems to fit the meaning - you *expose* your innermost feelings.